# Хліб тостовий чи тостерний?

Tags: вибір-слова, стилістика

Була сьогодні у Сільпо ТРЦ Victoria Gardens. Однак при виборі хліба, який використовую для приготування тостів, звернула увагу на назви двох видів: **тостовий** і **тостерний**.

[image: хліб тостовий]
[image: хліб тостерний]

У **[СУМі-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/tost)** цих слів не подають, лише слово "тост" зі значенням, яке, очевидно, не підходить:

> **ТОСТ**, у, чол. Коротка застільна промова з побажанням чогось і пропозицією випити чарку на честь кого-, чого-небудь.

Отож, як правильно, ***хліб тостовий чи тостерний***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У [Словнику іншомовних слів](http://www.jnsm.com.ua/cgi-bin/u/book/sis.pl?Qry=%F2%EE%F1%F2&page=2&action=search&found=100) знаходимо:

> **Тост** - 1. Застольна промова з побажанням.
>
> 2. Підсмажені шматочки хліба.

Зрозуміло, що в наведеному вами запитанні, за твірне слово беремо **тост** у значенні *«підсмажені шматочки хліба».*

Щодо наведених прикметників у запитанні зверну увагу на суфікси:

1. У слові **тостовий** – суфікс **–ов-**, твірне слово –тост. Тобто, **тостовий** хліб-той, який використовують для виготовлення тостів.
2. У слові **тостерний** –суфікс **–н-**, твірне слово – **тостер**. Тобто тостерний хліб –той, який використовують для приготування у тостері.

Справді, якщо поглянути у різні інтернет джерела, то знаходимо вживання двох слів. Щодо суфіксів, то два з них є словотворчими і правильно вжиті у цих словах ([Український правопис](http://pravopys.net/sections/23/)).
 На мою думку, **тостовий хліб** – це кращий варіант для використання, у зв'язку з вищезазначеним тлумаченням.
У [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%85%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B1) також знаходимо варіант **тостовий хліб.**

На жаль, ніяких словникових статей щодо правильності вживання **тостерний** не знайшла.